# Selecting nested common attributes

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using the following statement to query my db and return the most common color, style of item a. Once I get that data, I would then like to select the most common size.

```
select color, style, size
from orders
where item = 'item a'
group by color, style
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

If I group by color, style, size, it won't count the number of color, style properly. How might I get this last piece of info from the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, it's hard to see how one query would be more efficient than three.  But if you have to, you can merge them into a single query with a `union`:

```
select  'Common Color' as Id
,       (select color from orders where item = 'item a' group by color 
           order by count(*) desc limit 1) as Value
union all
select  'Common Style'
,       (select style from orders where item = 'item a' group by style 
            order by count(*) desc limit 1)
union all
select  'Common Size'
,       (select size from orders where item = 'item a' group by size 
            order by count(*) desc limit 1)
```

The subqueries are there to remove any ambiguity about wether the `limit` applies to the entire union or just one part.

Answer (score 0):

Use a second query to get the most common size

Comment: Is there a more efficient way? I figured I could do it in the same statement.